# hline not filling up in tabularx

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabularx

I created a table with the following code:

```
\begin{tabularx}{14cm}{|X|X|X|X|}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{\cellcolor{gray!20}contentcontent}} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|p{\linewidth}|}{contentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontent} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{\cellcolor{gray!20}contentcontent}} \\
\hline
\textbf{contentcontent:}& \footnotesize{contentcontent}& \textbf{contentcontent:} & \footnotesize{contentcontent}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{\cellcolor{gray!20}contentcontent}} \\
\hline
\textbf{contentcontent:}& \footnotesize{contentcontent}& \textbf{contentcontent:} & \footnotesize{contentcontent}\\
\hline
\textbf{contentcontent:}& \footnotesize{contentcontent}& \textbf{contentcontent:} & \footnotesize{contentcontent}\\
\hline
\textbf{contentcontent:}& \footnotesize{contentcontent}& \textbf{contentcontent:} & \footnotesize{contentcontent}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{\cellcolor{gray!20}contentcontent}} \\
\hline
\textbf{contentcontent:}& \footnotesize{contentcontent}& \textbf{contentcontent:} & \footnotesize{contentcontent}\\
\hline
\textbf{contentcontent:}& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{contentcontent}\\
\hline
\textbf{contentcontent:}& \footnotesize{contentcontent}& \textbf{contentcontent:} & \footnotesize{contentcontent}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{\cellcolor{gray!20}contentcontent}} \\
\hline
\textbf{contentcontent 1:}& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{contentcontent}\\
\hline
\textbf{contentcontent 3:}& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{contentcontent}\\
\hline
\textbf{contentcontent 2:}& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{contentcontent}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{\cellcolor{gray!20}contentcontent}} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|p{\linewidth}|}{contentcontent} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\textbf{\cellcolor{gray!20}contentcontent}} \\
\hline

\end{tabularx}
```

And for some reason my h-line doesn't fill up fully on the right side.

[image: Table output]

What could be the issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behavior you are noticing is due to your `\multicolumn`s like

```
\multicolumn{4}{|p{\linewidth}|}{contentcontent}
```

In all these cases replace `p{\linewidth}` with `l` and the problem is solved.

An example which doesn't work with your settings

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx,colortbl,xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{14cm}{|X|X|X|X|}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{\cellcolor{gray!20}contentcontent}} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|p{\linewidth}|}{contentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontent} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{\cellcolor{gray!20}contentcontent}} \\
\hline
\textbf{contentcontent:}& \footnotesize{contentcontent}& \textbf{contentcontent:} & \footnotesize{contentcontent}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{\cellcolor{gray!20}contentcontent}} \\
\hline
\textbf{contentcontent:}& \footnotesize{contentcontent}& \textbf{contentcontent:} & \footnotesize{contentcontent}\\
\hline
\textbf{contentcontent:}& \footnotesize{contentcontent}& \textbf{contentcontent:} & \footnotesize{contentcontent}\\
\hline
\textbf{contentcontent:}& \footnotesize{contentcontent}& \textbf{contentcontent:} & \footnotesize{contentcontent}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{\cellcolor{gray!20}contentcontent}} \\
\hline
\textbf{contentcontent:}& \footnotesize{contentcontent}& \textbf{contentcontent:} & \footnotesize{contentcontent}\\
\hline
\textbf{contentcontent:}& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{contentcontent}\\
\hline
\textbf{contentcontent:}& \footnotesize{contentcontent}& \textbf{contentcontent:} & \footnotesize{contentcontent}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{\cellcolor{gray!20}contentcontent}} \\
\hline
\textbf{contentcontent 1:}& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{contentcontent}\\
\hline
\textbf{contentcontent 3:}& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{contentcontent}\\
\hline
\textbf{contentcontent 2:}& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{contentcontent}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{\cellcolor{gray!20}contentcontent}} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|p{\linewidth}|}{contentcontent} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\textbf{\cellcolor{gray!20}contentcontent}} \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

And this is how it should be (replacing `p{\linewidth}` with `l`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx,colortbl,xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{14cm}{|X|X|X|X|}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{\cellcolor{gray!20}contentcontent}} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{contentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontent} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{\cellcolor{gray!20}contentcontent}} \\
\hline
\textbf{contentcontent:}& \footnotesize{contentcontent}& \textbf{contentcontent:} & \footnotesize{contentcontent}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{\cellcolor{gray!20}contentcontent}} \\
\hline
\textbf{contentcontent:}& \footnotesize{contentcontent}& \textbf{contentcontent:} & \footnotesize{contentcontent}\\
\hline
\textbf{contentcontent:}& \footnotesize{contentcontent}& \textbf{contentcontent:} & \footnotesize{contentcontent}\\
\hline
\textbf{contentcontent:}& \footnotesize{contentcontent}& \textbf{contentcontent:} & \footnotesize{contentcontent}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{\cellcolor{gray!20}contentcontent}} \\
\hline
\textbf{contentcontent:}& \footnotesize{contentcontent}& \textbf{contentcontent:} & \footnotesize{contentcontent}\\
\hline
\textbf{contentcontent:}& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{contentcontent}\\
\hline
\textbf{contentcontent:}& \footnotesize{contentcontent}& \textbf{contentcontent:} & \footnotesize{contentcontent}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{\cellcolor{gray!20}contentcontent}} \\
\hline
\textbf{contentcontent 1:}& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{contentcontent}\\
\hline
\textbf{contentcontent 3:}& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{contentcontent}\\
\hline
\textbf{contentcontent 2:}& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{contentcontent}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{\cellcolor{gray!20}contentcontent}} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{contentcontent} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\textbf{\cellcolor{gray!20}contentcontent}} \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

---

Why your code doesn't work? Because your `tabularx` is `14cm` wide and your `\linewidth` is greater than that. The available space for a `p` column spanning the whole `tabularx` is `14cm-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth`, so if you want to use a `p` column, it can not be greater than that length. If you want to use a `p` column with the maximum length, use `p{\dimexpr14cm-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}`

---

### EDIT (in response to the OP's comment)

If you want automatical linebreaks in your table cells, this can not be done in `c` and `l` columns.

At this point, I suggest you to define

```
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr#1-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr#1-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}}
```

and replace all `c` columns with `C{<width>}` columns and all `l` columns with `P{<width>}` columns, as in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx,colortbl,xcolor}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr#1-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr#1-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{14cm}{|X|X|X|X|}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|C{14cm}|}{\textbf{\cellcolor{gray!20}contentcontent}} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|P{14cm}|}{contentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontent} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|C{14cm}|}{\textbf{\cellcolor{gray!20}contentcontent}} \\
\hline
\textbf{contentcontent:}& \footnotesize{contentcontent}& \textbf{contentcontent:} & \footnotesize{contentcontent}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|C{14cm}|}{\textbf{\cellcolor{gray!20}contentcontent}} \\
\hline
\textbf{contentcontent:}& \footnotesize{contentcontent}& \textbf{contentcontent:} & \footnotesize{contentcontent}\\
\hline
\textbf{contentcontent:}& \footnotesize{contentcontent}& \textbf{contentcontent:} & \footnotesize{contentcontent}\\
\hline
\textbf{contentcontent:}& \footnotesize{contentcontent}& \textbf{contentcontent:} & \footnotesize{contentcontent}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|C{14cm}|}{\textbf{\cellcolor{gray!20}contentcontent}} \\
\hline
\textbf{contentcontent:}& \footnotesize{contentcontent}& \textbf{contentcontent:} & \footnotesize{contentcontent}\\
\hline
\textbf{contentcontent:}& \multicolumn{3}{C{10.5cm}|}{contentcontent}\\
\hline
\textbf{contentcontent:}& \footnotesize{contentcontent}& \textbf{contentcontent:} & \footnotesize{contentcontent}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|C{14cm}|}{\textbf{\cellcolor{gray!20}contentcontent}} \\
\hline
\textbf{contentcontent 1:}& \multicolumn{3}{C{10.5cm}|}{contentcontent}\\
\hline
\textbf{contentcontent 3:}& \multicolumn{3}{C{10.5cm}|}{contentcontent}\\
\hline
\textbf{contentcontent 2:}& \multicolumn{3}{C{10.5cm}|}{contentcontent}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|C{14cm}|}{\textbf{\cellcolor{gray!20}contentcontent}} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|P{14cm}|}{contentcontent} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|P{14cm}|}{\textbf{\cellcolor{gray!20}contentcontent}} \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Leviathan You're welcome.

Comment: Got one more issue.. how can I add automatically linebreak in my table cells?

Comment: @Leviathan see the edit